# Как проверить приложения на айфоне?

Tags: xcode

Как проверить приложение на айфоне? На эмуляторе всё работает, хочу проверить на самом телефоне. Есть ли какой-нибудь хак или что-нибудь, чтобы получить ipa файл? Айфон с jail.

P.S начинающий

P.S.S использую Xcode 5.0.2 Mac OS X Mavericks на виртуалке.

Comment: http://www.alexwhittemore.com/developing-jailbroken-iphone-ios-401/
и так далее

Comment: Написал ответ, а потом увидел, что проглядел, что айфон у вас с jail.